# Call the "C++" Struct in C File

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem, that I explain below code, How Can I call the C++ struct in C file without any error ?

I have a `C++` library in my code, in the this library include this defines:

In the `C++` library code example.h:

```
struct P_BRIDGE;

  typedef void  (*CALLBACK_ENABLE_TRAPPING)          (const struct P_BRIDGE* bridge, bool enable, unsigned int timestamp);
    struct S_CALLBACKS
    {
        CALLBACK_ENABLE_TRAPPING        enableTrapping;

    };
```

And I want to call this struct in `main.c` file like this

```
    #include example.h
....
        extern P_CALLBACKS const p_callbacks;
          P_BRIDGE* bridge = NULL;
```

`
 I have this error :

```
Src/main.c:175:24: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'const'
Src/main.c:176:3: error: unknown type name P_BRIDGE'
```

Comment: Usually, it is possible to import *C* code in a *C++* project with `extern "C"` block. I am not sure about the opposite. That's because *C++* has been developed "kind of top of" *C* (they are two different programming languages anyway).

Comment: I can not see any relevant code which can be used to explore the problem.

Comment: I do not see any c++ code...

Comment: Please show an [mre], i.e. enough code to compile it to reproduce the compilation error. You have to declare `P_BRIDGE` and `STP_CALLBACKS` somehow, e.g. by including a header file.

Comment: But if I use main.c file like main.cpp there is no error. What is the reason for error ?

Comment: My guess is that C compiler doesn't recognize this `const` in the parameter declaration: `const struct P_BRIDGE* bridge`. Try removing it for a change and see whether it compiles or not.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I remove but I have this error Src/main.c:175:10: error: unknown type name 'P_CALLBACKS'

Comment: @NetworkStudent Without seeing enough code it is difficult to explain the error. `main.c` will probably be compiled as C while `main.cpp` will be compiled as C++.

Comment: @NetworkStudent I cannot find any P_CALLBACKS in your question. Is this unrelated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P_BRIDGE is a struct.  In C, the syntax for declaring a struct variable needs the word *struct* in front eg

```
struct P_BRIDGE* bridge = NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help I changed this and first line extern struct STP_CALLBACKS stp_callbacks; solved problem

Comment: @NetworkStudent If you want to use the same header file in C and C++ code you might have to use `#ifdef __cplusplus` `extern "C" {` `#endif` ...`#ifdef __cplusplus` `}` `#endif`